# Cannot find module error for Java while executing javascript code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm facing the following error message on Windows 10x64 for Java module while executing javascript code:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'java'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rau\Desktop\Test.js:1:12)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)"

var java = require('java');

var javaLangSystem = java.import('java.lang.System');
```

Comment: you should do `npm i java -S` in your project folder

Answer (score 1):

The `java` module is not automatically available (i.e. it is not included with node.js ). It is available through the npm registry: https://www.npmjs.com/package/java

What this error is trying to tell you is it looked in all the paths for the `java` module and could not find it.

Make sure you have the java module installed via:

```
npm install java
```

Comment: I tried following command
npm install java -g
npm list java ==> Output => <drive>:\nodejs    `-- java@0.11.1
However when I tried to import java it says cannot find module 'java'